# How do I change the email I use to log in to Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, email

I want to change my Stack Exchange account email, because I cannot log in to that email. I rarely use that email, which was only used for registering with Stack Exchange in the very early days.

After I saw Google [recently announce](https://blog.google/technology/safety-security/updating-our-inactive-account-policies/) that they would delete inactive accounts after two years, I tried to log in to the email, but I failed even though I remembered the password.

I am afraid this could cause some problems in the future.

I found my "My Logins" page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/1637673

But I could only remove the login, and I don't know if it's safe to remove the current email and add a new Stack Exchange account (not Google or Facebook logins), because I can't log in to the current email.

Comment: Add a new login and remove the old one

Comment: @Petəíŕd The Linux Wizard
Please notice, I can only add google login, but I want to add stackexchange login
Now, there is no button to add a new stackexchange login

Comment: Try "Settings" -> "Your logins" -> "Add more logins..."

Comment: @Petəíŕd The Linux Wizard
Different, but I get.  In old days,  I can create a `stackexchange account` (this account is belong to stackexchange , not  other logins [google, facebook].  Now,  add login only allow account belong to [google, facebook] .

Comment: At first, I am searching a way to add old stackexchange account but nothing found, so come up this question

Comment: That "duplicate" doesn't answer the question. I have wanted to change the email I use to log in to SE sites, but I want to preserve my reputation on (some - it doesn't matter on all - sites), but I refuse to create either an account with google or with facebook.

Answer (score -2):

There is a help article about this

[How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials)

1. Go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/me
2. Then click "Add more logins"
3. Fill up and submit the Add a new login form,

[image: Add login Stack Exchange form]

Comment: Hmh, why downvotes?